# Magento 2: Get Customer data after login with observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer, login, magento2.2

I need to detect in frontend section for my custom module if customer has just successfully logged in, and i need to run some function before it redirect to another page, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use **customer_login** event observer for customer login action

**1) Create events.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**2) Now create observer CustomerLogin.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CustomerLogin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        echo "Customer LoggedIn";
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        echo $customer->getName(); //Get customer name
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i get customer session in this observer?

Comment: Yes you can get customer data from $observer. check my updated `customerLogin.php`

Comment: hi @prince patel is this event/concept used for to logged customer while using in REST Apis?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to check customer is logged in.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $customerSession;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
){
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function execute()
{
    if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
          //some logic
    }
}
```

to check customer just logged in you could observe "customer_customer_authenticated" event

> Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_customer_authenticated">
        <observer name="vendor_customer_authenticated" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerAuthenticated" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomerAuthenticated.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class CustomerAuthenticated implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to check if customer has just logged in, not  checking whether customer is logged in or not

Comment: to check customer just logged in you could observe "customer_customer_authenticated" event

Comment: in that observer i try to check `if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {die('in');}` but it didnt effect at all

Answer (score 1):

Use to try below code..

Magento 2.3 not allowed to use CustomerLogin this kind of formats in observer class so kindly use 
  Customerlogin instead-of CustomerLogin class that would be work.

```
<?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

   use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

   class Customerlogin implements ObserverInterface
   {        

   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {   
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customerdata.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    echo $customer->getName(); //Get customer name
    $logger->info(print_r($customer->getEmail(),true));
    die();
    }
  }
```

This is working well for me..

Happy Coding!!