# Customer redirect issue with plugin method magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, redirect, around-plugin

I have used below code to write plugin method for loginPost controller.

this is the code of etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="MyCucomtLoginAccountLoginPost" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

And i used below code in LoginPost.php

```
<?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer;

    use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
    use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
    use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface as ScopeConfig;
    use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
class LoginPost
   {
protected $session;
/** @var Validator */
protected $formKeyValidator;
/** @var CustomerRepositoryInterface */
protected $customerRepositoryInterface;
/** @var ManagerInterface **/
protected $messageManager;
protected $_objectManager;
/** @var Http **/
protected $responseHttp;
protected $currentCustomer;
protected $_customer; 
protected $_storeManager;    
protected $resultFactory;
protected $redirect;
protected $accountRedirect;
protected $resultRedirectFactory;

public function __construct(
    Session $customerSession,
    Validator $formKeyValidator,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    ResponseHttp $responseHttp,
    ScopeConfig $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer,
    UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
    AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
)
{
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->session = $customerSession;
    $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
    $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->responseHttp = $responseHttp;
    $this->_customer = $customer; 
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager; 
    $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
    $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
    $this->resultRedirectFactory       = $resultRedirectFactory;
}
public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $result) 
{       
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;        
    if ($subject->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $subject->getRequest()->getPost('login');

        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {

            $customerId = $this->getCustomer(trim($login['username']));

            $currentCustomer = $this->getcurrentcustomer($customerId);
            $status = $currentCustomer->getCustomerActivated(); 
            try {
                if($status == 0){                       
                     $message = "This account is awaiting activation.";                      
                     $this->messageManager->addError($message);                     
                     $result->setPath('customer/account/login');
                     return $result;                         
                }else{                                          
                    $configValue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard', $storeScope);

                     if ($configValue == 1) {
                        /* $url = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account');                      
                        $this->responseHttp->setRedirect($url);      */ 
                        $result->setPath('customer/account');   
                    } else {
                        $redirectUrl = $this->session->getBeforeLoginUrl();
                        $this->session->unsBeforeLoginUrl();
                        $result->setPath($redirectUrl);                                                 
                    }

                    return $result;
                }
            }
            catch (\Exception $e)
            {
                $message = "Invalid user Credentials.";
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                $this->responseHttp->setRedirect('customer/account/login');

            }
        }            
    }

}

/**
 * @param $email
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
 */
public function getCustomer($email)
{
    try{
        $websiteID = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer = $this->_customer->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteID)->loadByEmail($email);
        $userId = $customer->getId();           
        return $userId;
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}

public function getcurrentcustomer($id){
    $customerObj = $this->_customer->create();
    $customer = $customerObj->load($id);
    return $customer; 
}

public function getStoreId()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}
 public function getWebsiteId(){
   return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
  }

}
```

Problem here i am facing is It is always redirect to customer Dashboard once the customer is logged in.

I have set Option as "No" in backend for this setting under Login Options

Redirect customer to Account dashboard after logging in => **NO**, If that is set **"YES"**, that time only it should redirect to dashboard, but its not working properly.

What code i need to use to make it work? Thanks

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: Let me check now, I seen now

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: Vendor\Customer\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost::$resultRedirectFactory in this line, getting this error

Comment: check my update and remove var/ generated/

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 1 for Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::create(), called in  now this error i am facing

Comment: Check my message in chat box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84858/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-jafar-pinjar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use aroundExecute() :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface as ScopeConfig;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;

class LoginPost
{
    protected $session;
    protected $formKeyValidator;
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $responseHttp;
    protected $currentCustomer;
    protected $_customer;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $accountRedirect;
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    public function __construct(Session $customerSession, Validator $formKeyValidator, CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface, ManagerInterface $messageManager, ResponseHttp $responseHttp, ScopeConfig $scopeConfig, \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer, UrlInterface $url, \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultRedirectFactory)
    {
        $this->scopeConfig                 = $scopeConfig;
        $this->session                     = $customerSession;
        $this->formKeyValidator            = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->messageManager              = $messageManager;
        $this->responseHttp                = $responseHttp;
        $this->_customer                   = $customer;
        $this->_url                        = $url;
        $this->_connector                  = $connector;
        $this->_objectManager              = $objectmanager;
        $this->_storeManager               = $storeManager;
        $this->accountRedirect             = $accountRedirect;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory       = $resultRedirectFactory;
    }
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $loginPost, $result)
    {
        //your code logic
        $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();// URL is checked to be internal in $this->_redirect->success()
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($redirectUrl));
        return $resultRedirect;

    }
}
```

You can redirect by this code :

```
if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
```

This will redirect to home page if customer is login. If you want to redirect on `customer/account/login` page, still you can't able to redirect same page. Because, core magento also redirect on home page if logged in customer will access `customer/account/login` this page.

You can refer these both file :

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/Login.php
vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: hi, @Rohan, not understood clearly, will all my custom logic works if i use your code, because everything is working now, only redirect is the issue

Comment: I don't want to set custom path, if setting is Yes in admin panel, it should go to dashboard else it should be in same page, Please read my issue once

Comment: Magento also by default provide like that, if setting is no then it will redirect to home page. If you want to redirect in same page then you should add controller path in my answer.

Comment: In my case its not working, i do not know why, but i overrided only this file, @rohan

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: i do not want to redirect to home page, instead it should stay in same page

Comment: You mean in previous page from where you redirect to login page?

Comment: yes, previous page

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84857/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-jafar-pinjar).

Comment: Not able to login even if entered correct password

Comment: hi @Rohan, if customer not exist, it is showing this error message "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.", can we hide this from the plugin?

Comment: hi @Rohan, this worked as expected but one thing i need to change, if customer not logged in with correct password, i still redirect him to login page only

Comment: Best practice is that you can create separate question for that. It will helpful for other developer also for future. So, please create new question.

Comment: hi @Rohan, you can check here please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252248/customer-redirect-issue-with-login-post-plugin-magento2

Comment: hi @Rohan, could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $loginPost, $proceed)
{
    ...
    //if the config is not checked
    if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard')) {
      $currentUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl(); 
      header("Location: ".$currentUrl);
      die();
    }
}
```

Comment: This always redirect to home page is it?

Comment: @jafarpinjar yes it always redirect to home page

Comment: That is not my question, please read it once

Comment: @jafarpinjar check my updated question

Comment: hi, @blue, i do not want to redirect to home page, if setting is NO in admin, it should stay in same page, else it has to redirect to dashboard. I don't want to redirect anywhere like homepage or other pages, it should work like default magento, your code is to redirect to home page, that is not at all required

Comment: @jafarpinjar check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84851/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-blue).

Comment: hi @blue
i have many if else conditions, where do i need to put your code, can you please update it to my LoginPost.php file

Comment: Used your code, but after login also it stays in the login page

Comment: @jafarpinjar maybe your plugin is not running, try use observer instead of plugin https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178884/72667

Answer (score 0):

Update: We need to create 2 plugins, i.e. one for setting redirect URL (referrer URL) and other for redirection.

> **Step 1:** Define the plugins in **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="conditional_redirect_after_login" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\LoginPost" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login">
        <plugin name="set_redirect_url" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Login" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> **Step 2:** Plugin for setting up redirect URL in **app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Login.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Login {
    protected $redirect;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession) {
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function beforeExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login $subject
    ) {
        $redirectUrl = $this->redirect->getRefererUrl();
        $this->customerSession->setBeforeLoginUrl($redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

> **Step 3:** Redirect plugin file **app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/LoginPost.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class LoginPost {

    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $result
    ) {
        $configValue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('guest_wishlist/general/enabled', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        if ($configValue == 1) {
            $result->setPath('customer/account'); // Change this to what you want
        } else {
            $redirectUrl = $this->customerSession->getBeforeLoginUrl();
            $this->customerSession->unsBeforeLoginUrl();
            $result->setPath($redirectUrl); // Change this to what you want
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

**Note:** This code is not complete. This is just for indication.

Comment: hi @mohit, I am looking for code to stay in same page or referer page if setting is yes

Comment: Referer page for login post action will be login action. Which is not possible to redirect after login.

Comment: so, it is not possible to stay in same page after login, if the setting is yes in admin?

Comment: Are you trying to login using ajax popup?

Comment: no, default login not using ajax pop up

Comment: Then what do you mean by current page? Do you mean, the page from where the user went to the login page?

Comment: yes, exactly, is that can be done?

Comment: yes @jafarpinjar, please check the updated answer.

Comment: hi @mohit, can i use aroundExecute because everything logic i written is working fine,

Comment: For which plugin?

Comment: I have used aroundExecute but in your answer you are suggesting to use afterExecute

Comment: Please avoid around plugin. Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: $this->session->getBeforeLoginUrl(); this always giving empty value

Comment: @jafarpinjar, Please check the code now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84896/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-mohit-kumar-arora).

Comment: hi @mohit, used your code, it worked partially, i am adding condition by status, please check my updated question