# Customer redirect issue with login post plugin magento2

Tags: customer, redirect, after-plugin

I have used two plugins to use the referral url's for customer login page.

here is the code of my etc/di.xml

```
  <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="conditional_redirect_after_login" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login">
        <plugin name="set_redirect_url" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\LoginCheck" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
```

Code of LoginPost.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer;
 use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
 use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
 use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface as ScopeConfig;
 use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
 use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
class LoginPost
{
protected $session;
/** @var Validator */
protected $formKeyValidator;
/** @var CustomerRepositoryInterface */
protected $customerRepositoryInterface;
/** @var ManagerInterface **/
protected $messageManager;
protected $_objectManager;
protected $_connector;
/** @var Http **/
protected $responseHttp;
protected $currentCustomer;
protected $_customer; 
protected $_storeManager;    
protected $resultFactory;
protected $redirect;
protected $accountRedirect;
protected $resultRedirectFactory;

public function __construct(
    Session $customerSession,
    Validator $formKeyValidator,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Inkind\Navision\Model\Connector $connector,
    ResponseHttp $responseHttp,
    ScopeConfig $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer,
    UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
    AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
)
{
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->session = $customerSession;
    $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
    $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->responseHttp = $responseHttp;
    $this->_customer = $customer; 
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->_connector = $connector;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager; 
    $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
    $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
    $this->resultRedirectFactory       = $resultRedirectFactory;
}
public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $result) 
{       
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;        
    if ($subject->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $subject->getRequest()->getPost('login');

        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {

            $customerId = $this->getCustomer(trim($login['username']));
            if(isset($customerId) && $customerId!= ''){
                $currentCustomer = $this->getcurrentcustomer($customerId);

                $status = $currentCustomer->getCustomerActivated(); 
                $configValue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard', $storeScope);    
                try {
                    if($status == 0){                       
                        $message = "This account is awaiting activation.";
                        $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                        $this->session->logout();                   
                        $result->setPath('customer/account/login');

                        return $result;                      
                    }else{                                      
                        if ($configValue == 1) {
                            $result->setPath('customer/account');   
                        } else {
                            $redirectUrl = $this->session->getBeforeLoginUrl();
                            $this->session->unsBeforeLoginUrl();
                            $result->setPath($redirectUrl);                                                 
                        }   

                        return $result;
                    }
                }
                catch (\Exception $e)
                {
                    $message = "Invalid user Credentials.";
                    $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                    $this->responseHttp->setRedirect('customer/account/login');

                }
            }else{
                $message = "The email address was not recognised!";
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $result->setPath('customer/account/login');                         
                return $result;                             
            }

        }            
    }

}

/**
 * @param $email
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
 */
public function getCustomer($email)
{
    try{
        $websiteID = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer = $this->_customer->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteID)->loadByEmail($email);
        $userId = $customer->getId();           
        return $userId;
    }catch (\Exception $e){

        return false;
    }
}

public function getcurrentcustomer($id){
    $customerObj = $this->_customer->create();
    $customer = $customerObj->load($id);
    return $customer; 
}

public function getStoreId()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}
public function getWebsiteId(){
   return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
   }
 }
```

Code of LoginCheck.php

```
class LoginCheck {
protected $redirect;
protected $session;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
    $this->session = $customerSession;
}

public function beforeExecute(
\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Login $subject
) {
    $redirectUrl = $this->redirect->getRefererUrl();
    $this->session->setBeforeLoginUrl($redirectUrl);
    }
  }
```

This is working as expected, but i still want to redirect to login page if customer is not logged in with correct password.

Right now it is redirecting to referral url if not logged in correctly. Anyone please check it and help me . Thanks

Comment: Have you check log file?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya,  there is no error in log, i think its not any error related , we need to check the conditions.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, could you check how to redirect to login page if logged in with incorrect password?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, have you checked it?

Comment: Do you want to like that whenever customer add username and password and execute login button and before that you want to check customer id pw right?

Comment: @RohanHapani, yes as per above code if customer entered invalid password, it is redirecting to referral url. not to the login page, i need to redirect to login page

Comment: @RohanHapani, can we add any condition to $result? to check whether logged correctly or not?