# magento 2 logout customer after successful registration

Tags: magento2, customer, login, registration, logout

I need to logout the user after successful registration. How can I achieve this,

Is there a admin settings in backend to do this.

Answer (score 2):

How about going in the Magento backend, and set up the account setting to require customer to confirm his email (see screenshot below)

[image]

with this setting, once your customer has created his account, he won't be logged in. The screen will be like below:

[image]

Comment: that could be good idea !

Comment: thanks Amit! good to e-meet you star of StackExchange :-)

Comment: After clicking the link in my email it logs me in, it should not do so.

Comment: Facing the same issue. I am working with Acount approval by admin using this https://github.com/amitshree/magento2-account-approval. This extension has logout when registration but its not working for me. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256434/magento-2-logout-customer-after-successful-registration-works-only-first-time?noredirect=1#comment361146_256434

Comment: that is the same issue but with an additional module that I have not used before. I'd need to install the module and look at reproducing your issue. Unfortunately this is not something I have the time to look at. Apologies Fernandus

Answer (score 1):

magento does have a setting like this. You have to do customization.

In this case, you have to use two events

First,`customer_register_success` and `customer_data_object_login`,

When Customer is register then `customer_register_success` fire  first then

`customer_data_object_login` fire.

On  `customer_register_success` event add a registry variable

and then  `customer_data_object_login` event catch this registry and run  logout function.

The use of Registry flag, to prevent logout function on every `customer_data_object_login`  observer call.

As we know that `customer_data_object_login` is called when customer is loggeding.

**Create events.xml at app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/etc/frontend:**

and code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Amit Bera
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2018 amitbera.com (https://www.amitbera.com/)
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd"> 
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="customer_register_success_set_flag"
                  instance="{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Observer\customerRegisterSuccessObserver"/>
    </event> 

    <event name="customer_data_object_login">
        <observer name="customer_data_object_login_customer_logout" 
                  instance="{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Observer\CustomerDataObjectLoginObserver"/>
    </event> 
</config>
```

**Set registry variable, so  create an observer class 
 `customerRegisterSuccessObserver`.php at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/Observer`**

And code is:

```
<?php
namespace {Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Observer;


class customerRegisterSuccessObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {

        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        if($this->registry->registry('customer_register')){
            $this->registry->unregister('customer_register');
        }
        // register flag
        $this->registry->register('customer_register', 'yes');
    }

}
```

**check registry variable and fire logout so  create another observer class 
 `CustomerDataObjectLoginObserver`.php at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/Observer`**

*and code is:*

```
<?php

namespace {Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Observer;


class CustomerDataObjectLoginObserver  implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession        
    ) {

        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }   
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /**
         * Check variable and logout
         */
        if($this->registry->registry('customer_register')
                && $this->registry->registry('customer_register') == 'yes'){
            $this->customerSession->logout();
        } 
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Note that code is not test, post on base on idea.

Comment: I tried to redirect the customer in customer_register_success so that login wont happen it dint work I also tried this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/magento-2-redirect-user-to-specific-page-after-register

Comment: redirection is not the solution. You have to log out on `customer_data_object_login `event.

Comment: Kindly find this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256159/magento-2-logout-after-registration I posted this.

Comment: Its only working before logging in a new user.
After clearing cache and when I register a user it logout the user and for second third ... it works perferct, If I login a user and come back and create a new user it's not working it takes me to home page. If I clear cache again it works. Not sure why its happening.

Comment: I will try in Logging out in customer_data_object_login now  ASAP

Comment: I tried this code getting the same issue, Kindly find https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256434/magento-2-logout-customer-after-successful-registration-works-only-first-time?noredirect=1#comment361146_256434

Comment: I made a echo and exit in CustomerDataObjectLoginObserver When I loging from the login page customer_data_object_login is triggered but with registration process its not triggered but it logs me and gets me to the Home page

Comment: Thanks a lot Amit, I have tried in multiple ways but nothing works. Not sure and cant track why this happens in my website. I can find one thing that it looks to be cached. dont know how to clear them. in home page.

Comment: Hi Amit, Do you know why customer_data_object_login is not triggering when registration process login but triggers in login page. Cant find the solution for my issue.

Comment: I am sure that `customer_data_object_login` should  run.if the line L373 https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php#L373 code  is executed then `customer_data_object_login` then this observet must.Please check the same on default magento

Answer (score -1):

It can be easily done by the following module.

https://github.com/amitshree/magento2-account-approval/blob/master/Plugin/Customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php

Done by 2 methods

1.Event **`customer_register_success`**

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->coreRegistry->register('is_new_account', true);
    }
```

2.Override **`Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect`**

```
    $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
    // Adding a custom message
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Your account is not approved. Kindly contact website admin for assitance.'));
    // Destroy the customer session in order to redirect him to the login page
    $this->session->destroy();
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result */
    $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('customer/account/login'));
    return $result
```