# magento 2 logout customer after successful registration works only first time

Tags: magento2, customer, login, registration, logout

I have implemented this logic to logout customer after registration, Its only working before logging in a new user.

After clearing cache and when I register a user it logout the user and for second third ... it works perferct, If I login a user and come back and create a new user it's not working it takes me to home page.

If I clear cache again it works. Not sure why its happening.

[Magento 2 - Redirect user to specific page after register](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/magento-2-redirect-user-to-specific-page-after-register)

Comment: Write your code here, how you have tried.

Comment: I am using this extension https://github.com/amitshree/magento2-account-approval this extension has the same code with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131850/magento-2-redirect-user-to-specific-page-after-register no changes with the code i did.