# How to implement the following event in Magento : As soon as the customer logs in the details are printed in the log file

Tags: magento2.3

I have to print the login details of the customer and when he logged in, into the log file. How to implement the following problem in Magento 2.

Comment: I need to print in customer log and not just fetch details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event `customer_login` which will give you all customer data. Check here.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178884/49826

For print in logs do as below.

> Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="LazyCoder\PaymentDeadlines\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Obsever/CustomerLogin.php

```
    <?php
namespace LazyCoder\PaymentDeadlines\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $name =  $customer->getName(); //Get customer name


        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logfile.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($name); // Simple Text Log


    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use this within the execute function within the observer?

Comment: can you provide me the controller file how to call this observer?

Comment: No need for controller You only need to create observer and print data to log using above code.

Comment: My observer file:

Comment: public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {   
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customerdata.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    echo $customer->getName(); //Get customer name
    $logger->info(print_r($customer->getEmail(),true));
    die();
    }

Comment: but it is not generating the log

Comment: Give permission to var folder it will. Leave log for now, Print just customer email and exit code if you can see email printed then debug for log ahead.

Comment: normal printing of the name is happening but no log is generated, based on the answers given in the above link you commented

Comment: Try this Its similar but little bit different https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92442/49826

Comment: Does this worked ?!

Comment: No still no log

Comment: Wait I'll give you complete code.

Comment: Check I've updated whole code Its working for me, New log file geneeated and also prints my name :) Just to inform you have you run upgrade after creating xml and observer file Its necessary if not please do that and also apply permission to var folder to create new file.

Comment: Yes I have run the upgrade. ok let me try and will let you know

Comment: yes It worked thank you so much